# How to modify card popup Woocommerce with custome code?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, popup, cart

I want to add customize text on header of cart popup but I can't find where should I put my custom code.
I see a lot of plugin that have custom content in cart popup but I can't customize with these plugin so please help to add my custom code to cart popup.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZPHY.png)

I have try cart.php but it make change to cart page not cart popup

Answer (score 1):

You need to use minicart.php to modify the cart popup content. if you are using default woo-commerce then below is the file path :

```
woocommerce/templates/cart/mini-cart.php
```

here you can add customize text on header of cart popup.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code snippet in your active theme's `functions.php` file -

```
function add_custom_header_in_cart() {
    echo 'YOUR_HEADER_GOES_HERE';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart', 'add_custom_header_in_cart' );
```